# Expo Router not detecting filesystem changes

Tags: react-native, expo, expo-router

I have recently been introduced to expo router, and right now I am working on an app using it. Things have been going smooth for the first day. However, by the second day, when I wanted to add a third page to the app, a login page, which would become the default page of the app, I started experiencing weird issues with expo router that ended up taking the whole day trying to figure out what is wrong with my folder structure/code, but to no avail.

My current folder structure is as follows:

```
src/app
    - (main)/
        - _layout.tsx (uses <Tabs> with 2 Tabs.Screen, one with "page1", one with "page")
        - page1.tsx
        - page2.tsx
    - _layout.tsx (uses <Stack> with 2 Stack.Screen, one with "login" and one with "(main)"
    - login.tsx
```

From what I read in the docs, and also by looking at the template and other example code, this folder structure should be valid for what I want. However, when running my app, I get a warning from expo saying that `No route named "login" exists in nested children: ["(main)", "_sitemap", "[...404]"]`.

For some strange reason, `login` does not show up in the nested children list? I tried renaming the login file to `index.tsx`, it still didn't show up, instead now complaining "index" does not exist in the same nested children list. I restart the expo server, same error. I move `index.tsx` formerly `login.tsx` to a folder "(auth)", and change the stack screen name to "(auth)", and still "(auth)" does not exist in nested children.

After not solving what seems to me as a bug for a long time, I started trying more desperate experiments, I rename "(main)" to "(ddddd)", and now the nested children list changes to: `["(main)", "(ddddd)", "_sitemap", "[...404]"]`. It detected the new folder "(ddddd)", but it also kept believing that "(main)" still exists, and using the sitemap I could even navigate to it.

I thought this must surely be a caching issue, I removed `node_modules`, removed the npm cache, deleted temporary files in `/tmp` that seemed related to expo, npm, or metro, then ran expo with the `--clear` flag, but still `No route named "(auth)" exists in nested children: ["(main)", "_sitemap", "[...404]"]` (I renamed `(dddddd)` back to `(main)`, it detected that).

Just for clarification, `(auth)` is indeed inside `src/app`.

I tried a bunch of other folder structures, names, etc, and they all give the same weird behavior. Somehow changes to `(main)` get detected, even though it doesn't invalidate the old paths. But any other file/folder in `src/app` is simply ignored. While looking at people having similar issues, I often found people complaining that expo-router has no way of having non-path files inside `app`, I seem to have the complete opposite :(.

Since I had manually installed expo-router, and not used the template, I attempted to replicate the same thing with the template, and it gave me similar issues, changes to `(tabs)` got detected, but any other folder or file was simply ignored. The changes to `(tabs)` also got had the weird behavior where `(tabs)` would still show up in the nested children list while it had already been renamed.

I believe this to be a bug with expo router, and it maybe has to do with my system configuration (Arch btw). I just wanted to make sure I am not missing anything stupidly obvious before filing a bug report.